# Mathematics textbooks to understand Jackson electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I want a very solid mathematics background that will make going through Jackson's text less challenging. What books would you recommend?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise what you need help on? Is it vector calculus, i. e. things like the curl, divergence and Stokes Theorem? Or Green's functions?

Comment: I definitely need help with Green's functions. I just want a list of books I can go to for relevant mathematics. I feel like my foundation is a bit weak, so I just want to go over everything again but at a deeper level.

Comment: Then perhaps Chapters 7 and 8 of [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03834.pdf) may be of use to you. They give about 20 pages worth of background on tempered distributions (in order to define the Dirac delta function rigorously) and then define Green's functions. Is that enough or do you need more material?

Comment: div, grad, curl and all that by h m schey available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/H.M.ScheyDivGradCurlAndAllThat/page/n4)

Comment: @MaxLein Your notes look good. If you have anymore material I would like to see it.

Comment: At the end of each chapter in Jackson is a list of references. Look at the references therein.

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend the 2nd edition of my text, "Classical Electromagnetism"?
Chapter 5 does a thorough job on Green's functions.

Comment: There are many books with this title.  Which one is yours?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0486813711?pf_rd_p=c2945051-950f-485c-b4df-15aac5223b10&pf_rd_r=MYH5ZYXN1BJJXM4TRPNC